# How to share files on double-NAT

Tags: networking

How to make computers on both networks "see" each other and share files, maybe even smb discovery ?

- "Router2" is my ISP Modem/Router and I need to have it because it supports faster VDSL speeds than my other router
- I can't use bridge mode because I think I won't be able to connect directly to it like PC5 and PC3
- I can't use "router1" as modem/router because it doesn't support VDSL
- I need router1 for bandwidth control, Can I use it as a switch, disable DHCP with Bandwidth control still functioning?

[image]

Comment: What is the model name of router1 ? How many devices are connected on it ?

Comment: Switches are best used as switched, while a router typically does everything a switch does, the additional features often are overkill.  You are better off just getting a switch in cases like that.

Comment: @EchoMike444 TD-W8950ND V2, Multiples phones/Laptop through wifi and 1 PC throw ethernet

Comment: @Ramhound My main reason for using "router1" is to control bandwidth, Will a switch have the same features, Or turning the router to just a switch and disabling NAT / DHCP make it act like a switch while still controlling bandwidth ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On PC3 and PC5,add a static route to the other network

windows, commandline)

```
route add 192.168.2.0  mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.10
```

This assumes that your router 1 behaves like a normal router (not a NAT router).

Comment: Can I do the same route on "router2" instead of each PC on the switch ?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can turn your "router1" to an AP. First you need to determine the IP address pool range of router2. Then choose an unassigned IP address for router1. Now assign an unused IP address to router1. Now turn DHCP off in router1. Connect two router's LAN port with an ethernet cable. Restart both routers. Now you can use router1 as an AP. Then you connect to router1 and you will be able to solve file sharing problems on double NAT network.

Comment: But will I still have the bandwidth controlling functionality in router1 on PCs connected to it ?